# Spring Rest Controller handling java.util.Optional using Jackson

Tags: spring, rest, jackson, java-8

I have got Spring RestController classes to handle rest services using JSON. For JSON I am using Jackson. There are fields of java.util.Optional type

```
 private Optional<Long> start = Optional.empty();
```

To enable the handling of Optional type, I am configuring the Spring as follows

```
 <bean id="objectMapper"  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="modulesToInstall" value="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module" /> 
  </bean>
```

However when I call the webservice, it fails in deserializing the Optional types with following message

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
   Could not read JSON: Can not instantiate value of type 
   [simple type, class java.util.Optional<java.lang.Long>] 
   from Long integral number (3424323423432); no 
   single-long-arg constructor/factory method
```

Doing serialization/deserialization from stand alone code works fine. There I register the module directly using the following code

```
    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    m.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

Versions I am using:

Spring : 4.1.5.RELEASE

Jackson: 2.5.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Optional` is not meant to be used as field.

Answer (score 4):

I could figure out this. The solution is to register the object mapper to Message converter as follows

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="modulesToInstall"
        value="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using latest version of Spring-boot then you could achieve this by adding the following dependency in the pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

[Spring blog says :](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)

> Some well known Jackson modules are automatically registered if they are detected on the classpath:
>
> - jackson-datatype-jdk7: Java 7 types like java.nio.file.Path (as of 4.2.1 release)
> - jackson-datatype-joda: Joda-Time types
> - jackson-datatype-jsr310: Java 8 Date & Time API data types
> - jackson-datatype-jdk8: other Java 8 types like Optional (as of 4.2.0 release)

And if you want to use the mapper in your code, auto wire the JacksonObjectMapper.

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;
```

Then use the above Spring container's mapper instance to convert Object to String

```
jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works for Spring 4.
Just make sure you're using the latest xsd's in your xml configuration.

In my situation it was somehow referencing '*spring-mvc-3.0.xsd*' and this version does not know the 'mvc:message-converters' tag yet. Changing it to '*spring-mvc.xsd*' solved this issue.